# Ask database admin password in order to make certain actions in Odoo 12

Tags: database, odoo, odoo-12, erp

I want to know if there is a way to ask the password used in the odoo database login before excuting a specific action. I add a button to validate records and make them uneditable and undeletable once they have been validated. I want to add another button to unvalidate already validated records, but ask for the admin password in order to do it

Comment: Why the admin password? Why not just using Odoo's access groups and for example showing the button to a special access group or just checking access on the method behind that button against access rights?

Comment: I thought about it, but I'm been asked to use a password, the same password as the admin